# Dynamic arrays in C++ compared to Java

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Recently, I started to learn C++ after I have learned Java, and I was instructed to make a dynamic array, so I tried to make a temp variable which contains what I need and then reassign it into the variable I actually want to use.

```
void Pile::grow(Stone s){
    Stone temp[getLength() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(temp) / sizeof(temp[0]); ++i) {
        if (sizeof(temp) / sizeof(temp[0]) < 28){
            temp[i] = stoneArr[i];
        }
    }
        
    stoneArr = temp;
}
```

But the compiler is giving me an error that I cannot reassign it, for some reason I just can't understand.

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of C array. and it'll be fine. Don't use C arrays like this. It is not a dynamic array! For that you must know the array size at compile time what you don't know there... Also what is `stoneArr`? It is not java. Forget everything about that. You are much closer to the metal now...

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, the size of an array must be a compile time constant. `std::vector` can/should be used here.

Comment: What's the significance of the number `28` here?

Comment: i will try and use vectors guys, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> `void Pile::grow(Stone s)`

You are not using `s` anywhere. Are you supposed to add it to the new array you are trying to create?

> `Stone temp[getLength() + 1];`

This is not legal in standard C++. The size of a fixed array must be known at compile time.

Some compilers support "variable length arrays" as a non-standard extension, but do not rely on them if you need to write portable code. See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/)

To allocate an array dynamically at runtime, use the `new[]` operator instead, eg:

```
Stone *temp = new Stone[getLength() + 1];
...
delete[] temp;
```

Or, use the standard `std::vector` container instead, eg:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Stone> temp(getLength() + 1);
...
```

> `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(temp) / sizeof(temp[0]); ++i)`

You cannot use this `sizeof` trick on a dynamic array, let alone a VLA. `sizeof` is evaluated only at compile time, not at runtime.

Since you are copying values from an existing array, use the length of that array instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getLength(); ++i)
```

> `if (sizeof(temp) / sizeof(temp[0]) < 28)`

Hard-coding a `28` here makes no sense. In fact, this whole `if` check needs to be removed completely.

> `stoneArr = temp;`

This assignment will not work when `temp` is a VLA. And `stoneArr` can't be a VLA anyway.

`stoneArr` needs to be either a `Stone*` pointer to a `new[]`'d array (that is managed by following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)), or a `std::vector<Stone>` (preferred).

With all of that said, try this instead:

```
private:
    Stone *stoneArr;
    int arrLength;

...


Pile::Pile()
    : stoneArr(NULL), arrLength(0) {
}

Pile::Pile(const Pile &src)
    : stoneArr(new Stone[src.arrLength]), arrLength(src.arrLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i) {
        stoneArr[i] = src.stoneArr[i];
    }
}

Pile::~Pile() {
    delete[] StoneArr;
}

Pile& Pile::operator=(const Pile &rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
        Pile temp(rhs);
        std::swap(stoneArr, temp.stoneArr);
        std::swap(arrLength, temp.arrLength);
    }
    return *this;
}

int Pile::getLength() const {
    return arrLength;
}

void Pile::grow(const Stone &s){
    Stone *temp = new Stone[arrLength  + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i) {
        temp[i] = stoneArr[i];
    }
    temp[arrLength] = s;
        
    delete[] stoneArr;
    stoneArr = temp;
    ++arrLength;
}
```

Or:

```
#include <vector>

private:
    std::vector<Stone> stoneArr;

...

// std::vector follows the rule of 3/5/0, so let the
// compiler handle Pile(), Pile(const Pile &), ~Pile(),
// and operator= for you...

int Pile::getLength() const {
    return stoneArr.size();
}

void Pile::grow(const Stone &s){
    stoneArr.push_back(s);
}
```